Zod Validation for array of instance File
I am making post form for a social media project and I am using zod for validation
and this the solution in TypeScript but I am using JavaScript
z.object({
    file: z.custom<File[]>()
})

How can I write this in Js
I am not sure it my first time using zod

Just omit the type parameter? But using zod with plain js is a kinda strange choice.

According to the documentation, your implementation of custom does not do any validation. https://zod.dev/?id=custom-schemas
